# Given $n$, determine positive integers $x,t$ such that $(2^n)!= 2^{xn+t} k$ where $k$ is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Now we can write $(2^n)!= 2^{xn+t}k$, where $x,t$ and $k$ are positive integers such that $k$ is odd. How do we  determine $x$ and $t$ based on $n$?

Comment: Does trying some examples for small $n$ suggest a pattern?

Comment: kinda difficult since with n = 5 it's already too big

Comment: Since the asker is primarily concerned with the exponent on $2$, the problem reduces to adding up all powers of $2$ that divide numbers below $2^n$. This means looking at, at most, $2^{n-1}$, so it isn't too awful.

Comment: This post is unclear. For the unique $m$ such that $(2^n)!/2^m$ is an odd integer, what is the point of writing $m$ under (one of the many!) the form(s) $xn+t?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really comes down to a question of "How many $2$'s are there "below" $2^n$?"

On the surface, there are $\left\lfloor\frac{2^n}{2}\right\rfloor=2^{n-1}$ even numbers. Then half as many multiples of $4$, and half again as many multiples of $8$, et c. At each level, you would add that many $2$'s to your count. So you have $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k=2^n-1$$ total $2$'s in the number $(2^n)!$. But this is exponential, so it should be pretty clear that $xn+t$ doesn't really cut it.

Answer (score -1):

By [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula), the integer $m$ such that $\frac{(2^n)!}{2^m}$ is an odd integer is given by
$$m=\sum_{i=1}^n2^{n-i}=2^n-1,$$
and rewriting it $xn+t$ makes no sense.

Comment: If the downvoter thought this new answer duplicates the old one, (s)he forgot to consider the improvement brought by mentionning (and linking to) Legendre's formula.